How to detect partial file transfer during FTP in python?
I'm using python's pyftpdlib for FTP server and ftplib for FTP client to facilitate file transfer. If the FTP connection closes before the entire file being shared, how to ensure that the FTP server identifies the partially received file so that it can be removed?

Hardly with a plain FTP transfer, as the connection close is actually the only indication that the transfer has completed. So you cannot distinguish transfer that completed properly and transfer that completed prematurely.
Only if your transfer uses an additional layer that has clean "end" indicator, you might be able to tell that something went wrong. Such layer can be:

TLS/SSL encryption
zlib compression
block mode transfer

But you cannot enforce these from server side (except for not allowing transfer unless the user configures client the way you need). Also they help you only to identify connections broken due to external causes (like a network outage). If the connection is closed by the client, it may properly close even the additional layer (like the TLS encryption).

As you noted, there's on_incomplete_file_received event. I cannot imagine that the event can be really useful, as per my explanation above. Even the comment in pyftpdlib source code says

If we used channel for receiving we assume that transfer is finished when client closes the connection".

If you interrupt the upload on client, the client is closing the connection, so the transfer will be considered complete.

Related question, where I suggest some alternative approaches:
How to detect that a file is being uploaded over FTP
Though they require cooperation on the client side.
